# Reusing cookie in curl not working

Tags: php, curl, cookies

first time here, and I need help, please!

I have two functions that do different things. The first, only do a login in an external website, and its working fine. In the second fuction, I need to do a **POST** with the login saved from the first. I use the **CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR** and **CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE** with the same path in both functions, but when I print what I'm sending in each function with **var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch))**, the cookie only shows in the first one, and not in the second, causing a **401 Unauthorized Server** as a result of the second function.

```html
<?php

$cookie_path = dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $login_conf['login_url']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $login_conf['referer_header']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_path);

$html = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

Thats basically the content of the login function, and this:

```html
<?php

$cookie_path = dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt';

$ch2 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, $purge_conf['request_url']);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_REFERER, $refheader_submit);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query_purge);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE );
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: '.strlen($query_purge))
);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_path);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_path);

$html_purge = curl_exec($ch2);
?>
```

Is the other one, that I need to sent a json post to other page, for witch I need to keep the login and cookie.

I dont know if I am doing something wrong, or if I am missing something.

Comment: Are the two requests sent to the same domain? Have you verified that cookie.txt was actually written into?

Comment: Cookies are sometimes not shared between different subdomains(For example, a cookie for website.com would not work on www.website.com unless you tell it to). Did you verify both use the exact same domain name? and if not, have you defined it to work on both domains?

Comment: Yeah, cookie.txt has data and it's writable, so I think that it's not a problem from the cookie... In the other hand, it's my first time using curl and I'm not sure if it's writing all the info needed or if it's missing something.

The domain it's the same, yes, but I've noticed that when I do the login it's "auth.domain.com" and when I want to do the next curl, the url it's "gateway.domain.com". Is that a problem? How can I configure it to work with both domains?